# UITableVIew dynamic height with aspectratio contentview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout

Already read [Auto-Layout: Get UIImageView height to calculate cell height correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041820/auto-layout-get-uiimageview-height-to-calculate-cell-height-correctly),the answer works well in ios 8 with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, however it is not suitable for lower ios version.

I have created a dynamic height `UITableView` with `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize`.

There is a square `UIImageView` in each cell, I want `UIImageView` keep square  in both iphone 5 and iphone 6/plus. So I set constraints to the imageview as :
[image]

The image view's height is set aspect ratio 1:1 to its width, and both the constraints on leading and trailing keep the imageview's width is equal to the cell. The bottom space from the imageview's bottom to the content view's bottom is 29 pixel.

Moreover, I wrote the code in the tableview delegate like

```
override  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
     return cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height+1;
}
```

However, the result is not as same as what I predicate, the imageview is very long :
[image]

the red color is the background of the image view.

So what's going on?

Comment: Make sure the image views masks to bounds is set to true, also known as clipsToBounds depending on whether you want to do it in IB or code

Comment: I have already set clipsToBounds, but I think the problem is about the systemLayoutSizeFittingSize method is not correct figure the height for the cell.

Comment: When heightForRowAtIndexPath is called, has iOS already computed the size of what is going into the contentView?

Comment: TO Mike Taverne: Since heightForRowAtIndexPath is a delegate method, ios UITableView still does not know what's the real height of such cell until the delegate method return a height.