# UITableView and automatic height

Tags: uitableview, swift, autolayout

OK so I have a `UITableView` and a custom `UITableViewCell`. This custom cell has a title, below that a sub-title, below that a `UIImageView` (aspect fit) and below that a button. Now the titles will always be one line of text so the only element with varying height is the `UIImageView`. Now I've assigned the following constraints:

`title label - top space 8px, left space 8px, right space 8px`

`sub-title label - top space 10px, left space 8px, right space 8px`

`image - top space 20px, left space 8px, right space 8px`

`button - top space 8px, left space 8px, bottom space 40px`

Now I didn't give the image view a height or width constraint because the images will be of varying size. I was also sure to create a trail of constraints going from the top of the cell to the bottom. I also set `postTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to automatically adjust the cell height and gave a fair estimate of the height.

However when I run the application there is a HUGE amount of space at the top and bottom of the image view. Which is strange because I set a constraint on the image to be 20px below the sub-title label, and I set a constraint on the button to be 8px below the image, which does not happen AT ALL. What could be the issue here? The constraints I posted above are the only constrains on the entire view.

Comment: post image of what happen and what you want

Answer (score 1):

Ok so figured it out, for anyone who stumbles upon this the issues is the image aspect fit mode which throws off the cell height calculation. What you have to do is apply the constraint manually before setting the UIViewImage.image.

See this for more info: [Auto-Layout: Get UIImageView height to calculate cell height correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041820/auto-layout-get-uiimageview-height-to-calculate-cell-height-correctly)